# Как использовать three js без модуля

Tags: javascript, html5, three.js

Как использовать three js без type="module"

```
<script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'three';

        import {
             OrbitControls
         } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

         
        import {
            ConvexObjectBreaker
        } from 'three/addons/misc/ConvexObjectBreaker.js';

        import {
            ConvexGeometry
        } from 'three/addons/geometries/ConvexGeometry.js';

       
</sciprt>
```

без этого в three js ничего работать не будет,а я хочу чтобы код был в

```
    <scirpt>
/* Some code */
    </script>
```

раньше для этих целей использовал

```
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
```

а сейчас такое работать перестало!

Comment: а в чем проблема использования type="module"?

Comment: мне так не нравится , когда я пише следующий скрипт вне type="module" нельзя обращаться к функциям созданным в type="module" а эти функции без three js не создаются

Comment: как я и написал в вопросе ранее - http://threejs.org/examples/js/ тут раньше всё было и работало без type="module" но сейчас перестало ,там ничего нету

Comment: как по мне новый  type="module" просто супер) на ноде юзаю это уже пару лет) в чем именно у вас проблема при использовании, я уверен, решается все достаточно просто

Comment: я создал класс внутри type="module"
<sciprt type="module"> class Game{ constructor(a){ 
this.a =a;
} }
var b = new Game();
</script>

console.log(b) //но тут ничего нету

а в консоли теперь пытаюсь его вывести console.log(

Comment: а кажись я нашел ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Я почти не сомневался, что вопрос просто решается.. очень просто

Comment: не,не сработало ,вопрос остается тем же

Comment: `<script type="module">
    class Game {
        constructor(a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
    var b = new Game();
</script>
<script>
    console.log(b);// выводит что нет b
</script>`

Comment: ты объявляешь переменную внутри модуля. Она доступна только внутри модуля, пока ты ее не экспортируешь. После этого, для использования в другом модуле - необходимо ее импортировать